# Don't see the "helpful flags" link on my profile

Tags: support, profile-page, flag-history, helpful-flags

I can see the *helpful flags* link in my SO profile. But I can't find it in meta profile.

Is this normal? where can I find it?

Comment: Have you actually flagged anything on MSO?

Comment: yes. I flaged 2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The link should appear as soon as you have at least one flag **marked as helpful**. It does not appear if you only have declined and/or pending flags.

You can [visit the link manually](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/187870) (this link is specific to you) if you're curious about pending flags, etc. You can figure out your flag summary link by editing the URL to insert your user ID:

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/USER_ID
```