# Link to flag summary is not shown if you have flagged for the first time but the flags have not been approved / rejected yet

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, profile-page, flag-history

I first experienced this today, when I flagged a question for the first time on the StackApps Q&A. When I had flagged the question, I went back to my profile where I couldn't find a link to my flag summary.

[image: Profile without "helpful flags" link]

*There is no "helpful flags" link*

Then I went to my StackOverflow profile, on which the "helpful flags" link was already present. I copied the link `http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1419007` and changed the site and userId (`http://stack`**`apps`**`.com/users/flag-summary/`**`12680`**. At this page, I was able to see that my flag had not been processed yet.

However, the "helpful flags" link did not appear on my profile until the flag got approved (about 6 hours later). I think it's unnecessarily confusing that you can't see* which posts you've flagged until at least one of your flags gets approved.

[image: There is a "helpful flags" link displayed at the profile page]

I'm not sure if this is by design (although it appears to be [a known thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135938/188498)), but in my opinion users should be able to figure out where their flags went, **especially** if they are new to a site (meaning they didn't flag anything before).

**TL;DR**: The "helpful flags" link doesn't appear until at least one of your flags gets approved. IMO, this should be changed so the link will be displayed if you've got any pending flags as well.

* *Okay, **technically** you can see it. But new users don't even **know** where to find it, and even more experienced users will have to **dig** to get there.*

Comment: Note that this question was actually asked *before* the "duplicate", but this question was closed instead of that one because this question is worded as a bug report instead of as a feature request.